# Why is Seahorse messing up my Samba sharing?

Tags: samba, seahorse

I am having a miserable time trying to Samba files to share correctly. I loaded Seahorse in the terminal and got an error. I'm sure my networking issue is a permission problem.

```
nighthawk@Core4:~$ seahorse
** Message: init gpgme version 1.2.0

(seahorse:3619): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: Read-only property 'window' on class 'SeahorseViewer' has type 'GtkWidget' which is not equal to or more restrictive than the type 'GtkWindow' of the property on the interface 'SeahorseView'


(seahorse:3619): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: Read-only property 'icon' on class 'SeahorsePkcs11Certificate' has type 'gchararray' which is not equal to or more restrictive than the type 'GIcon' of the property on the interface 'GcrCertificateIface'
```

The terminal hangs at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a seahorse bug see here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/908440